# Xcode7.3 dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode7

I've been working on my Simulator throughout the development of my App, then I decided to make my test on iOS devices. Then, I started running into this

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D204992A-FBED-4E71-A2F7-6EDF6E63D4C0/App.app/App
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D204992A-FBED-4E71-A2F7-6EDF6E63D4C0/App.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D204992A-FBED-4E71-A2F7-6EDF6E63D4C0/App.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking'
```

And after looking through many SO questions and gone through `cocoapod's`github gists which were all based on Last year's posts, so I updated my cocoapods to the beta 1.0.0Beata-8 and then I started having a `Parsefacebookutils` header errors in my Xcode7.3. So, I disabled bitcode, and set Non-Modular to yes and the error persists, so I switch back to the stable 0.39 of `Cocoapods` and I'm back here. I added `Pods framework` to the `Embedded Frameworks` in my App Target. Checked my `Build Phases` for  `Check Pods Manifest.lock,  Embed Pods Frameworks,  Copy Pods Resources` they exist. My `Runpath Search Paths` has `@executable_path/Frameworks` in it. And I've cleared my derived data too. So, I'm confused on what I need to do

Comment: delete the derived data  and try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've done that. And I just did again and not working

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of the SSL issue, I had set my developer, distribution certificates on my Mac(Keychain) to 'Always Trust' for one of my other project. I had to change them back to 'Use System Defaults'. It worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all kinds of method. But for me ,it's SSL issue.
if you can run the project in the simulator but crash in your iphone.
Maybe the answer is your SSL issue.
I change my certificates on my mac to "Always Trust".
At last i reset it to "Uswe System Defaults".
then it worked.